# Can´t edit css in Browser because of HTML Form and css class

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, forms

I had a Problem with my Development console in Chrome. All stylings of the Site where only available in Read-Only Mode. It wasn´t possible for me to edit the styles in Chrome.
But i just ignored it because i just created new classes in Chrome to test new stylings.

After changing some HTML code suddenly it was possible to edit the stylings again in Chrome. After some copy and past from the old code I found what creates this Bug. It was a little Form.

```
<div class="search-map-form">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="ORT ODER POSTLEITZAHL">
        <input type="submit" value="SUCHEN">
    </form>
</div>
```

But it is not only the form that causes this Bug. It is the combination of the class `search-map-form` AND the form.

Changing the class name to `search-map-forms` -> there is no Problem.
Delete the form but leave the div with the class -> No Problem.
Deleting only one input -> No Problem (it doesn´t matter which)

Has anyone experienced something similar? Or does anyone know why this happen?

I really don´t get it.

UPDATE: 
Now it gets more confusing. I tried to replicate it on a clean html page. Nothing happens i switch back to the page with the Problem, reload it (without the same code i had the Problem)... No Problem anymore. Even the code on the Server i haven´t touched since 2 days works now. 
It must be a client sided Problem but I really don´t know what this caused and why I had this Problem for 1 week and suddenly cant reproduce it anymore. Without really changing anything.
After Browsing a few minutes. Reloading the Page on the server and the Problem is back again...

Comment: It shouldn't be caused by specific classes or elements combination. Normally it can occur because of a faulty extension or invalid css sheets that are pre-included. However the fact that only with a certain combination of markup produces the problem causes me to believe that you enter some strict-cache scenario. Try going in developer tools settings -> preferences and checking "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" under the network category, reset chrome and try again.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov My Cache is already disabled.